# Cannot import sparknlp on Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I'm trying to do an

```
import sparknlp
```

on the Databricks platform and I'm getting a similar message to the one reported at [After installing sparknlp, cannot import sparknlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705164/after-installing-sparknlp-cannot-import-sparknlp)

I can't figure out how to get the python wrapper installed... I can access the spark-nlp library via Scala but I can't get the python version working.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

These error can be produced due to sparknlp jars have been loaded correctly, but python wrappers library can not be imported. Make sure you have installed those wrappers correctly. Check out the [sparknlp documentation site](http://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/quickstart.html)

As is said in documentation webpage, make sure that after install python sparknlp library:

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ spark-nlp==1.5.4
```

that your environment variable PYTHONPATH can locate sparknlp wrappers.